# Javascript Distance Calculation Returns NaN

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a function to calculate the distance between two sets of latitude and longitude coordinates I get from the Google Maps API

Here is the calculate distance function:

```
function getDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {

    var lat1p = parseFloat(lat1);
    var lon1p = parseFloat(lon1);
    var lat2p = parseFloat(lat2);
    var lon2p = parseFloat(lon2);

    var R = 6371; // km (change this constant to get miles)
    var dLat = (lat2p-lat1p) * Math.PI / 180;
    var dLon = (lon2p-lon1p) * Math.PI / 180;
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180 ) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180 ) *
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    var d = R * c;
    if (d>1) return Math.round(d)+"km";
    else if (d<=1) return Math.round(d*1000)+"m";

    return d;
}
```

I believe all the coordinates are considered Float types I'm not 100% sure but when I have it print or alert what the distance is it returns NaN.... Is there a way to do this. I'm trying to stray away from the Google Maps API to calculate distance because that would make everything harder because I would essentially have to start over.

Comment: You should debug this by checking the result of every intermediate calculation, to track down where the NaN is coming from.

Comment: I've found that complicated javascript calculations almost always require you to wrap the intermediate values in parseFloat(x):

var c = 2 * parseFloat(Math.atan2(...));

You just keep wrapping values until it stops converting to strings

Comment: `parseFloat` might return `NaN`. Set a breakpoint and inspect the variables. Learn how to debug your code: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners.

Comment: @David: If a function returns a number, like `Math.atan2`, then you certainly don't need `parseFloat`. Just throwing in `parseFloat` randomly does not really help. Understanding where exactly the calculation goes wrong is better.

Comment: @FelixKling my example could have been better (I just grabbed one of the lines above), but the advice wasn't too far off.  Once you have what should be the correct calculation, you often need to walk through it in a console looking at the intermediate values for unexpected type conversions.  Even when you know the rules, it's not always clear why a conversion is taking place.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I fixed it I was double declaring variables as well as I had a . instead of a , when I called the distance function. Thank you guys for your suggestions they led me to figure it out.